# Ruby on rails Supersized

Tags: jquery, plugins, ruby-on-rails-4, supersized

im having issue with the pipeline of ruby on rails and the integration of supersized.

i downloaded the latest release of supersized and wanted to use the slideshow one 
buildinternet.com/project/supersized/download.html 
but im having some issue with the pipeline

i was trying to use rubygems.org/gems/sprockets-urlrewriter
but i don't understand this line:

In rails, within your own initializer:

Rails.application.assets.register_preprocessor 'text/css', Sprockets::UrlRewriter
 does anyone know how i can integrate supersized with ruby on rails or if anyone know an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Im answering to my own question i have founded how to manage rails pipeline with supersized 
so i share with you a link with a Test rails project using supersized :[The link for the Test](http://github.com/Benaouda/Test)  enjoy